# Java Clickthrough Opaque JFrame

Tags: swing, jframe, mouseevent

I am creating a program which will act as a live wallpaper and playback a gif. Currently, I can play a gif animation correctly via an undecorated full-screen JFrame. The problem is that I cannot place a JFrame further behind desktop icons. Ideally I want my JFrame to be clicked through as if it were transparent, without actually setting my JFrame background & content pane background transparent.

Is there a way to do this in Java or must I move my project over to C++?

Comment: No it's not possible in Java. You cannot forward mouse events back to the OS.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Would you know what programming languages are capable of this? I would assume that authentication would be troubling in this type of program. Additionally if this is possible on other languages, can Java use the native keyword to run that function?

Comment: Java cannot do this things because it's a cross platform language. I would reccomend to use a OS native programming language (for example Visual C++ or C# for Windows).